# ExternalInterface: cant't access some AS objects (movieclips) from a callback

Tags: actionscript, callback, externalinterface

basically, I have some functions in my as file. Some of them play with a mc instance. The instance is not available when calling the function that uses it as callback. Is there a way to solve?

Example.

AS

```
function B(){
    ExternalInterface.call('console.log','ok')//OK!!!
}

//italy is a MovieClip on the Main timeline
function A(){
    B();
 ExternalInterface.call('console.log',italy)//Error!
}

ExternalInterface.addCallback('test',A);

JS

$('flash').test();//flash is my html swf object
```

The error I get trying to reference italy from A (only) whem called from javascript:

uncaught exception: Error in Actionscript.

---

Basically, the italy movieclip is available through the AS functions. But it isn't available if I call an AS function from javascript. As you can see though, I see B from A. It's only Italy that I can't see. why?

Answer (score 0):

Hey, no, it's all ok, it works. It was a bad error inside one of my methods.

Sorry. Maybe moderators could delete this question. Bye!